# why is this not working (python)

Tags: python

```
score = 0
print("Question 1. What is 1+1?")
print("a) 2")
print("b) 4")
print("c) 11")
print("d) 3")
x = 0
line = input('Answer: ')
while line != "a":   
    x = x+1
    print('Incorrect, you have used',x,"of your 3 chances")
    if x == 0:
      break
print("Question 2. What is 10x22?")
```

meant to give you 3 tries then display whether the answer is correct or not. Also meant to break if the question is correct on the first or second attempt.

Comment: You do not ask for input **in the loop** so if one enters the wrong answer, `line` will keep the old answer. Furthermore you increment `x` so `x` will never be equal to 0 and thus the `break` will never happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get an answer inside the while loop so that the while loop will check if the user gave the correct answer.

There is also a problem with how you are using `x`. `x` will never be 0 so the break line will never be touched. See code below for solution to both problems.

```
score = 0
print("Question 1. What is 1+1?")
print("a) 2")
print("b) 4")
print("c) 11")
print("d) 3")
x = 0
line = input('Answer: ')
while line != "a":   
    x = x+1
    print('Incorrect, you have used',x,"of your 3 chances")
    if x == 3: # if the user uses their three chances, move to the next question.
      break
    line = input('Answer: ') # try to get another answer
else:
    print("You've selected the correct answer")
x = 0 # resets number of chances for the next question
print("Question 2. What is 10x22?")
```

I hope this answers your question. Happy coding!

Comment: doesn't work creates infinite loop if answer is incorrect and if correct doesn't state that it is

Comment: @john - I only addressed the problems in the post. You would have to add the code to indicate that the user answered correctly. I updated the answer to get rid of the infinite loop if answers are always wrong.

Comment: When answered correctly or incorrectly it uses all 3 chances and then moves to next question. I'd like the User to have 3 Individual chances.

Comment: @john - clarify for me. Does the user have three chances per question, or do they have three changes in the entire quiz?

Comment: It requires you to have 3 chances per question

Comment: @john - The answer has been updated to reset `x` to 0 before each question. This way, users have 3 chances per question.

Comment: Question 1. What is 1+1?
a) 2
b) 4
c) 11
d) 3
Answer: b
Incorrect, you have used 1 of your 3 chances
Incorrect, you have used 2 of your 3 chances
Incorrect, you have used 3 of your 3 chances
Question 2. What is 10x22?

Comment: This is what it does still

Comment: It still doesn't allow you to input individual answers to each question it skips all of 1-3 and goes to next question

Comment: @john - I updated the answer. I mistakenly didn't type `input` in the while loop.